# Apache Calcite to Find Selected Columns in an SQL String

Tags: java, apache-calcite, sql-parser

I have a use case where I want to know the columns which have been selected in an SQL string.For instance, if the SQL is like this:
`SELECT name, age*5 as intelligence FROM bla WHERE bla=bla`
Then, after parsing the above String, I just want the output to be: `name, intelligence`.
Firstly, is it possible through Calcite?
Any other option is also welcome.

PS: I want to know this before actually running the query on database.

Answer (score 7):

This is definitely doable with Calcite. You'll want to start by creating an instance of `SqlParser` and parsing the query:

```
SqlParser parser = SqlParser.create(query)
SqlNode parsed = parser.parseQuery()
```

From there, you'll probably have the most success implementing the [`SqlVisitor`](https://calcite.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/calcite/sql/util/SqlVisitor.html) interface. You'll want to first find a `SqlSelect` instance and then visit each expression being selected by calling visit on each element of [`getSelectList`](https://calcite.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/calcite/sql/SqlSelect.html#getSelectList--).

From there, how you proceed will depend on the complexity of expressions you want to support. However, it's probably sufficient to recursively visit all `SqlCall` nodes and their operands and then collect any `SqlIdentifier` values that you see.

Comment: Can you just parse part of the sql expression? e.g. parsing `SUM(amount)/Count(id)`  . I can make dummy sql but it'd be nice just to be able to parse a valid sql expression made out of sql functions.

Comment: You should be able to use the `parseExpression` method of `SqlParser` for cases like this.

Answer (score 0):

It can be as simple as:

```
SqlParser parser = SqlParser.create(yourQuery);
SqlSelect selectNode = (SqlSelect) parser.parseQuery();
SqlNodeList list = selectNode.getList();

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println("Column " + (i + 1) + ": " + list.get(i).toString());
}
```